# TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, INTERVAL and DST extravaganza

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, intervals, dst, postgresql-9.4

I'm working on a Rails application which stores all dates to PostgreSQL as "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE". (Rails handles the time zone on the application layer which for this application is "Europe/Berlin".) Unfortunately, Daylight Savings Time (DST) becomes an issue.

The simplified "projects" table has the following columns:

```
started_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
duration INTEGER
```

Projects start at `started_at` and run for `duration` days.

Now, say there's only one project which starts on 2015-01-01 at 10:00. Since this is "Europe/Berlin" and it's January (no DST), the record looks like this on the database:

```
SET TimeZone = 'UTC';
SELECT started_at from projects;
# => 2015-01-01 09:00:00
```

It should end on 2015-06-30 at 10:00 (Europe/Berlin). But it's summer now, so DST applies and 10:00 in "Europe/Berlin" is now 08:00 in UTC.

Due to this, finding all projects for which the duration has elapsed by use of the following query does not work for projects which start/end across DST boundaries:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE started_at + INTERVAL '1 day' * duration < NOW()
```

I guess it would be best if the above WHERE did the calculation in timezone "Europe/Berlin" rather than "UTC". I've tried a few things with `::TIMESTAMTZ` and `AT TIME ZONE` none of which has worked.

As a side note: According to the PostgreSQL docs, `+ INTERVAL` should deal with '1 day' intervals differently from '24 hours' intervals when it comes to DST. Adding days ignores DST, so 10:00 always stays 10:00. When adding hours on the other hand, 10:00 may become 09:00 or 11:00 if you cross the DST boundary one way or another.

Thanks a lot for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a function which calculates `ended_at` by adding `duration` days to `started_at` honoring DST changes of a given time zone. Both `started_at` and `ended_at`, however, are in UTC and therefore play nice with Rails.

It turns `started_at` (timestamp without time zone, implicit UTC by Rails) to a timestamp with time zone UTC, then to the given time zone, adds the `duration` and returns the timestamp without time zone (implicit UTC).

```
# ended_at(started_at, duration, time_zone)
CREATE FUNCTION ended_at(timestamp, integer, text = 'Europe/Zurich') RETURNS timestamp AS $$
  SELECT (($1::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE $3 + INTERVAL '1 day' * $2) AT TIME ZONE $3)::timestamp
$$  LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE SET search_path = public, pg_temp;
```

With this function, I can omit having to add `ended_at` as an explicit column which would have to be kept in sync. And it's easy to use:

```
SELECT ended_at(started_at, duration) FROM projects
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got two strategies for avoiding headache:

1. Let Rails handle everything to do with Timezones, so Postgres doesn't have to at all

or

2. Let Postgres handle everything to do with Timezones, so Rails doesn't have to at all

Mixing the two will always be a pain, and is basically what's causing your problems now. I'd go with strategy 1 (let Rails handle it). To do this, your Postgres database should store a start time, and a finish time, both in UTC. `duration` may be a thing in your user interface still, but if a user enters a start time and a duration, then you should calculate a finish time, and store that finish time in your database. The start time the users enters, and the finish time that you calculate in your app, with both be timezone-specific, and you just let Rails handle the conversion to UTC when it saves to the database.

Your query would then be simply:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE finished_at < NOW()
```

(BTW, You could also store the duration in your database, but it's superfluous, since it can be calculated from the start time and finish time)

Comment: That's certainly my plan B. But shouldn't it be possible - on the database layer - to take a WITHOUT TIME ZONE time, assign the implicit time zone UTC, convert it to "Europe/Berlin", add the interval and then convert it back to UTC?

Comment: TBH I'm not sure if that's possible or not. My experience though is that those types of calculations are much easier handled outside of SQL, even when they are possible.

Comment: I finally found a way to do the math on the database layer. However, I'll upvote your answer anyways since for a new application it's most certainly a valid alternative to store `started_at` and `ended_at` rather than the `duration` and then doing all the math on the app layer.